# Calculate the radius around a lat/lon GPS point in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, gps, coordinates, haversine

I'm trying to make a PHP script that can do something when a GPS device (tracker) enters a "geofence" with a predefined position. Most of the help I have found uses the haversine formula, but most try to get a nearest location from a point. I pretty much need the opposite.
The device and "fence location" coordinates are in a MySQL database, I am able to pull them sucessfully. Now I need to set the radius around the fence location center, which should be 10 meters in any direction from that point.
Whenever the device enters within this 10m radius, PHP does something.
So point A(lat,lon) has a 10m radius around it, device B is sending its lat,lon into the SQL database and whenever point A and B are within 10m of each other, something happens.
Where do I start? Is the haversine of any use in my situation?
I think PHP could caluculate the distance difference of A and B an whenever that distance is under 10m, PHP does something.

I think this could do the job.

```
function haversineGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000)
{
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  return $angle * $earthRadius;
}
```

Comment: php runs on a server. exactly how is it going to know where this gps device is, and what it's doing?

Comment: Both A and B coordinates are stored in an SQL database. A is always the same coordiate (it doesn't move), B is moving and updating its location to the database every X seconds, so the newest database entry is the latest position of B. I already have all of this working.

Comment: so when php updates the db, it does a select to calculate the distance between A&B, e.g. `if (dist($A, $B) < 10) { do_something(); }`

Comment: so you have a center coords and device coords, use [this func](https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php) to calculate distance and check it for being less than 10, then do things you wanted

Comment: Correct. I have found this code and I will try it out. Updated question.

Comment: @MarcB That code works beautifully, thank you! Is there a way I can flag your answer as correct?

Comment: can't accept comments (obviously they're not "answers"). And no worries, since it was only pseudo-code, it ain't really an answer either.

Answer (score 0):

So, to put it all into a complete answer:

Use a function similar to the one linked by @Gudz Daniel to calculate the actual distance from any givien point: https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php.  This draws an effective "Geo-fence" circle around that point, since you can measure your distance from any incoming angle.

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else {
    return $miles;
  }
}
```

Then, you simply do a comparison to whatever distance you would like the device to flag your next process, as pointed out by @Mark B:

```
$distance = distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, "M");

if ($distance <= 1) {
    // Now you know your truck/device is
    // within 1 mile of the center-point.

    send_alert("You've arrived!");
}
```